# Calculating Correlation Coefficient with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of values and a 1-d numpy array, and I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient using `numpy.corrcoef(x,y,rowvar=0)`. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testLearner.py", line 25, in <module>
corr = np.corrcoef(valuesToCompare,queryOutput,rowvar=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2003,  in corrcoef
c = cov(x, y, rowvar, bias, ddof)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1935, in cov
X = concatenate((X,y), axis)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
```

I printed out the shape for my numpy array and got `(400,1)`. When I convert my list to an array with `numpy.asarray(y)` I get **`(400,)`**!

I believe this is the problem. I did an `array.reshape` to `(400,1)` and printed out the shape, and I still get `(400,)`. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a workaround by creating a numpy array and just adding elements to that instead of appending to a list, but still I feel it should be possible to do this with lists once converted to a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have assumed that `reshape` modifies the value of the original array. It doesn't:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(5)
>>> a.shape
(5,)
>>> b = a.reshape(5,1)
>>> b.shape
(5, 1)
>>> a.shape
(5,)
```

---

`np.asarray` treats a regular list as a 1d array, but your original numpy array that you said was 1d is actually 2d (because its shape is `(400,1)`). If you want to use your list like a 2d array, there are two easy approaches:

- `np.asarray(lst).reshape((-1, 1))` – `-1` means "however many it needs" for that dimension".
- `np.asarray([lst]).T` – `.T` means array transpose, which switches from `(1,5)` to `(5,1)`.-

You could also reshape your original array to 1d via `ary.reshape((-1,))`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it did too. But that is the thing how can you have a (5, ) shape. it has to default to 1! There seems to be no point then having that conversion function if you can't use it with other original numpy arrays.

Comment: @Aladdin The point of a (5,) shape is that it's a one-dimensional array. (5,1) is then two-dimensional, and (5,1,1) would be three-dimensional. You absolutely can use it with other numpy arrays -- just ones of the same shape, and lists are considered to be 1d arrays. I added a description of how to make it a 2d array in my answer.